# Where to store a lists of all built-in functions and variables

Tags: c#, syntax, storage

I am trying to make code autocompletion for my project. Language for which, I am making an editor has some built-in functions and variables that are stored inside its compiler. I cannot access them in code(compiler is in c++ and my project is in c#). So I decided to copy them from compiler source files. The problem is that I don't know where to store them. **In a separate file or inside my editor code? And how to make it versionable?**

I thought about storing built-in syntax inside my projects code but again, I don't know how to make it versionable.

Comment: Have you looked at the formats for extensible IDEs like Visual Studio Code?  People are able to add new languages so you should be able to find documentation, discussions, etc.  Also, if you use VSC's format you can use VSC with your language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I decided to completely rework my autocompletion library.
As it was suggested in comments, I looked on VSCodes json files for languages, and it turned out to be the perfect format for my purpose. So I decided to use it.